# Execute only one role in my runlist

Tags: chef-infra

In my run list, I have two roles

```
 "run_list": [
    "role[web_server]",
    "role[web_client]"
]
```

I want to execute only one role for some nodes and another one role for some other nodes. How to do this? Is there any idea to put some condition over there? I dont want to change my runlist. I have this run list common for all nodes. but I want to execute one role for few nodes and another runlist for few nodes.
Any suggestions?

Comment: If you want different roles on each node, why would you want the same runlist?  Having some nodes run one role, and others run a different role is EXACTLY what a runlist is for.

Comment: How would you mark one node as a server and another as a client?

Comment: @TejayCardon I have a script to auto bootstrap a node  and within the script I have written my first json file with all my roles in that runlist. But I have execute some roles on few nodes and another some roles on other few nodes. Because in my autoscalling I don't know how many nodes are there? It will be suddenly increasing or decreasing. So, Depending upon some condition (for example If my chef server contains web_server file then It execute web_server role only.) I execute only some roles/recipes in that runlist and another some roles/recipes for another node

Comment: @coderanger I just write common runlist for all nodes but I dont want to execute all the recipes/roles present in that runlist. Is it possible to do? Because there are n number of nodes and I dont want to set seperate runlist for every nodes.

Comment: As Javier pointed out, you can't do any logic in a runlist, but you could use a role cookbook and put the logic within the cookbook.  If you really want to keep the runlist the same while conditionally executing the roles, then his recommendation is probably your best, and only, option.

Comment: You are using Chef incorrectly, stop doing that.

Answer (score 0):

First I would recommend you to reconsider your position to not have two different run-list. Is there any reason for that? Roles are not a popular way to manage tour infrastructure in Chef community right now.

Run-list is an array of roles and/or recipes and you cannot set any logic in it. You can approach what you want setting the node run-list with logic, or organizing your infrastructure using roles-cookbooks (cookbook acting like classic roles), usually called wrapper cookbooks, where you can put any logic you wish inside the recipes of the cookbooks. Check some links about the pattern of Wrapper Cookbooks like this, like this [one](https://www.chef.io/blog/2013/12/03/doing-wrapper-cookbooks-right/), to see some examples applying this.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a role cookbook, which is just a wrapper cookbook that acts like a role with a series of "include_recipe" lines of code to define your run list.  You could then have logic built into your "role" cookbook.